# xpath php select text and child node in order

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml like this:

```
<p>tex text</p>
<p><a2>subchild text</a2> text text text</p>
```

I would like to extract all text (from p and all child nodes) in written order and put the result in a string.
I use the following query

```
$text = $currentNode->xpath("p[not(@class='notes')]/text())
foreach($text as $tex) {
    $finalText .= $tex." ";
}
```

The problem is I cannot get the child-nodes text, for example text of node 'a2' in my example.
Any help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

/text () looks only for immediate text nodes, //text () looks for immediate or lower nodes. It's short for descendent-or-self::text ().

So your query just needs an extra slash:

```
$text = $currentNode->xpath("p[not(@class='notes')]//text());
```

(Assuming you want just the text and not copies of the child elements).

Comment: yes, It works, but I get child node with inverted order, for exemple in the above sample I get:  "tex text, text text text subchild text". Why?

Comment: What are you using? I've used xsltproc and php and both give the children in the expected order: <doc><p>text 1</p>
<p><a2>Text 2</a2> Text 3</p></doc> gives "text 1 Text 2 Text 3"

Comment: I am using SimpleXMLElement::xpath and php. I use xpath on simpleXmlObject

Comment: I'm not sure how conformant simpleXML is. Try using DomDocument and DOMXPath - that works.